# Infinite translate animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a very long image.

I want to loop animation of moving it from left to right.

Here is a video: http://youtu.be/OvXY6-US-MQ

Please take a look at the "city line" image animation (bottom one).
The problem is that free space when animation ends. How to make it really infinite?

Here is how I did what I have on video:

```
ivCity = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.city);
    ViewTreeObserver cityObserver = ivCity.getViewTreeObserver();
    cityObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            Log.d(TAG, "ANIMATION PRE DRAW");
            // Remove after the first run so it doesn't fire forever
            ivCity.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            cityWidth = ivCity.getMeasuredWidth();

            Animation _translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, getScreenWidth(), Animation.ABSOLUTE, -cityWidth + getScreenWidth(), Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f);
            //Animation _translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, getScreenWidth() - cityWidth, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 1.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0f);
            _translateAnimation.setDuration(10000);
            _translateAnimation.setStartOffset(0);
            _translateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            _translateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            _translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            _translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

            ivCity.startAnimation(_translateAnimation);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And the layout is:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/city_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_width="1657.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/city"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```